# Searching for particular answer that I've read in the past

Tags: discussion

First I would like to apologize if this is not right place to post this type of question. Please feel free to move it to correct place. I'm searching for three answers that I've read here on SO a while ago but now I cannot find them:

1. Was related to maintaining various versions of perl and I am not exactly sure but I guess that the Brian D Foy was describing how he is dealing with this problem.
2. Was regarding randomness and there were beautiful figures showing various functions on various OS. I guess that the figures were simmilar to those [here](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/oldtcp/tcpseq.html) and [here](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/oldtcp/tcpseq.html)
3. Was named something like: "what was your biggest eye opener" or "what was your biggest aha moment".

How should I find those questions or where should I post questions regarding finding them?

PS: I've found that some questions are deleted from SO e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243616/visualization-tools-for-huge-graphs/33529165#33529165) cannot be find on SO anymore but it is available in [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20151128003753/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243616/visualization-tools-for-huge-graphs) so I guess it is possible that those questions that I'm looking for might be deleted from SO and hence I cannot find them.

PPS: Why was mentioned question deleted?

Comment: Well, you could try to find the answer in Brian D Foy's profile.

Comment: Yes I can but there are lot of his answers.

Comment: You can still type searches within a user profile.

Answer (score 3):

Asking for off-site resources or tool recommendations are off-topic since some time. Now and then those questions gets attention, for example because it attracts new spammy answers, and a close vote is casted on such questions.

That is exactly what happened [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=27424728#27424728) and the final vote and subsequent deletion was done by a moderator.

For the under 10K users I've made a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8rFl.jpg) of the question you were looking for.

You have no other option then to use the archives if you want to find those deleted questions or become a member with 10K so you can see deleted questions. That would still require you have an url though, as only moderators can search in deleted content. I won't bother them with such requests. Feel free to hop in a chat room that has some regulars with high enough reputation. Most of them are open to provide you with a screenshot.

If you're interested in programs or libraries that meet certain strict requirements you might want to check [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). If you can't find what you're looking for, before asking read their [on topic page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and specially the [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)